# in webview external link not work in my app

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a problem with webview. In my app when i click a link it open with the default browser. But I want the link open with my own app. Please help how I do this
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private WebView webView ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView =findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.somoynews.tv/");


}
```

}

Comment: Show us your `xml` where the link is contained.

Comment: this is my xml<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



</WebView>

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Where does the link you click came from?

Comment: link open with my browser like chrome but I don't want it. I want link are open within my app

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```java
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.somoynews.tv/");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return false;
            }
            });

    }
```